# How can I do spell check with Membase ?

Tags: spell-checking, membase

I have a membase server and Have a list of words which is my dictionary. Now I have some words with which i can make spell check. I am not able to come up with some good algorithm. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: Found links i bookmarked a while ago. Got links from a similar SO discussion a while ago, maybe you can search for it.

Check out the following links. The first is an article on how to write a spell checker, the others are for making it faster:

http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

http://theyougen.blogspot.ca/2010/02/faster-spelling-corrector.html

Hope it helps.